# Lista de arrays em PHP

Tags: php, aplicação-web

Tenho um array com varios arrays dentro

Ex:

```
$menus = [
    [0] => [
        'menu' => [
            'href' => '/product',
            'menu' => 'Produtos'
        ]
    ],
    [1] => [
        'menu' => [
            'href' => '/category',
            'menu' => 'Categorias'
        ]
    ],
    [2] => [
        'menu' => [
            'href' => '/user',
            'menu' => 'Usuários'
        ]
    ]
];
```

Como posso fazer para incluir mais um array no ultimo array da minha lista de arrays.

Ficando assim no final

```
$menus = [
    [0] => [
        'menu' => [
            'href' => '/product',
            'menu' => 'Produtos'
        ]
    ],
    [1] => [
        'menu' => [
            'href' => '/category',
            'menu' => 'Categorias'
        ]
    ],
    [2] => [
        'menu' => [
            'href' => '/user',
            'menu' => 'Usuários'
        ],
        'submenu' => [
            'menu' => [
                'href' => '/user/list',
                'menu' => 'Todos Usuários'
            ],
        ]
    ]
];
```

Existe uma função para facilitar o trabalho?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o *array* for de índices numéricos e sequenciais, basta você contar a quantidade de elementos e acessar a última posição, que será a quantidade menos um.

```
$quantidade = count($menu);
$menu[$quantidade-1]['submenu'] = [
    'menu' => [
        'href' => '/user/list',
        'menu' => 'Todos Usuários'
    ]
];
```

Obtendo algo como:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [menu] => Array
                (
                    [href] => /product
                    [menu] => Produtos
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [menu] => Array
                (
                    [href] => /category
                    [menu] => Categorias
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [menu] => Array
                (
                    [href] => /user
                    [menu] => Usuários
                )

            [submenu] => Array
                (
                    [menu] => Array
                        (
                            [href] => /user/list
                            [menu] => Todos Usuários
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/UyuSnm) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/YellowSlipperyXuanhanosaurus)</sup>